# Rollreg and missing values in panel data

Tags: panel, stata

I have an unbalanced panel data of mutual funds data from 1981 to 2013 with monthly observations of their returns. I am trying to estimate betas with a rolling regression. The betas should be estimated on the excess return `exret` and market premium `rmrf` from the previous 12 months. Therefore I want to use `rollreg` command to estimate these betas and alphas. My problem is that there is missing values in `exret` or `rmrf` variables (although the id and time variables are non missing) and Stata doesn't run the regression.
My code is as follow:

```
tsset wficn date

rollreg exret rmrf, move(12) stub(retM12)
```

When I run this I receive the following message:

> Number of gaps in sample: 542
>
> Observations with preceding time gaps
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> sample may not contain gaps r(198);

Could someone help me ?

Comment: `rollreg` is a user-written command (SSC) and  and it's a good thing to mention this when asking in any forum. I've never used it, but you can also check `help rolling`, an official Stata command for rolling-window and recursive estimation.

Comment: Also posted and answered at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1297540-problem-with-rollreg-and-missing-values-in-panel-data It's a good idea in any forum to be explicit about postings elsewhere.